# VS2012: Clear the test results in Test Explorer when re-running a test that previously failed

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, test-explorer

On running an individual test in VS2012, a window is shown at the bottom of Test Explorer that includes (assuming failure) a red icon with "Test Failed" next to it.  There follows the failure message with "elapsed time" directly beneath.

I would like to know simply whether there is a way to clear this window.  For instance if I right-click my test and select "Debug Selected Tests", it is somewhat confusing as I step through the test that this test-results window still shows the failure from a past test-run.

Comment: I haven't seen anything related to this. I much prefer the Test Results window from previous versions.

Comment: I could not agree more - showing the results from past tests, with no ability to clear them, can be very confusing at times. I wish there was a way to clear previous results, but I have not found one.

Answer (score 53):

Actually, there is a way - clean and then rebuild your solution.
Previous test run results will clear right up.

Comment: Exactly, if you only re-build the test results are there, by choosing "clean" the results are removed. Great, thanks!

Comment: You only need to clean the project the tests are in - sometimes the buid time matters

Comment: Using VS 2017 with NUnit 2 Test Adapter extension, and this solution does not seem to work. I see the tests "refresh", but the previous results are still green. I appreciate that the Test Explorer is much faster and less buggy than previously, but I would like a way to clear results.

Comment: This solution DOES NOT WORK in Visual Studio 2019. See comminity post here, MSFT has not responded. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/457817/test-explorer-output-should-clear-previous-results.html

Comment: One must first Clean, then Rebuild.

Comment: Not a great solution for large projects that take a while to build.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, either. My `project\.vs\17\project\TestStore` directory has 1400 files in it and 378,000 directories ... no exaggeration!

Answer (score 5):

Switch the build to a different configuration - eg if in debug, switch to release. Then switch back to debug. This should cause it reload the tests. If vs fails to reload the tests on switching back - just do a build (not a rebuild) as this will trigger it to reload the tests

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: I thought this didn't work, but then I switched to this window to downvote it and went back to VS, and the tests had disappeared. Not sure what happened there. Maybe it worked?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Instead, you can filter which tests are shown to you, if that suits your needs. You can find more information about tests here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Delete the folder that contains the test results. This will have different names depending on which test suite you use.

The easiest way is to search *all of the files* under your solution to look for the name(s) of the test(s) that you want to remove. In my case there's a directory called TestStore. I delete that and my test explorer is now empty. Running Clean on your solution will also clear this directory.

There is also a sanctioned method that removes the test runs via the UI but I find it way to cumbersome. But you may like it. [How to: Delete Test Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms182502(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

You could make your tests sleep for a second when invoked:

```cs
[ClassInitialize()]
public static void Init(TestContext ctx)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

This is only a workaround, but it will at least give you the chance to see the Test Explorer progress bar moving, and won't leave you wondering whether anything has actually happened:

Comment: If you go along that path, you could also set a break point on the test's first row, debug test and and you'll also have a change to see a "refreshed" in progress icon in the tests results window.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2019 you can unload/reload the project with the tests in to clear the results.